# Spring Rest : Edit resource with patch

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, patch

In my code `venue` and `coach` are the entities and both have photos , When I patch the coach entity it works fine but when I wants to patch coach resource it gives me the following error 
someone can explain what is the problem?

**Coach.java**

```
@Entity
public class Coach implements CoachGetter,Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    private String extras;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private Sport sport;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="coach",targetEntity=CoachPhoto.class)
    private CoachPhoto coachPhoto;

    //getters and setters 
}
```

**Venuehoto**

```
@Entity
public class VenuePhoto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Venue venue;

    private String path;
    // getters and setters }
```

**CoachPhoto**

```
@Entity
public class CoachPhoto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Coach coach;

    private String path;

       }
```

**venue.java**

```
@Entity
public class Venue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    private Boolean enabled=true;

    private Double latitude;

    private Double longitude;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Sport> sport;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="venue",targetEntity=VenuePhoto.class)
    private List <VenuePhoto> venuePhotos;
    //getters and setters
}
```

**coach patch request**

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "id": 6,
    "sport": "http://localhost:3000/api/sports/6",
    "coachPhoto": {
        "id": 8,
        "path": "coachPhotos/8.jpg"
    },
    "extras": null
}
```

**venue patch request**

```
{
    "name": "National Stadium",
    "id": 5,
    "enabled": true,
    "latitude": 25.203927,
    "longitude": 55.271077,
    "venuePhotos": [ 
        {
            "path": "venuePhotos/3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "path": "venuePhotos/6.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

**error**

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to convert from type [java.net.URI] to type [com.ivl.MySportsAcademy.model.VenuePhoto] for value 'path'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI path. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: com.ivl.MySportsAcademy.model.Venue["venuePhotos"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:388) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:360) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:308) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:259) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:104) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:240) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1628) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1301) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.doMerge(DomainObjectReader.java:279) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.read(DomainObjectReader.java:87) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 101 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.net.URI] to type [com.ivl.MySportsAcademy.model.VenuePhoto] for value 'path'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI path. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable.
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.UriToEntityConverter.convert(UriToEntityConverter.java:119) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.6.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$UriStringDeserializer.deserialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:518) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:287) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    ... 110 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI path. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable.
    ... 113 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you also share the `CoachPhoto` and `VenuePhoto` classes?

Comment: @Bentaye please check the updated question

Comment: I don't think I can help, just an idea though, could it be that `Venue` does not implement `Serializable` and it behaves differently?

Comment: @Bentaye I have also implemented `Serilaizable` but nothing worked :|